# Django обновление страниц

Tags: python, django

Подскажите как обновить ту же страницу на которой я сейчас, никуда не редиректить, как в браузере нажать f5 ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел такой вариант

```
return redirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER','redirect_if_referer_not_found'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Если обновление по времени вас устроит то можно ограничиться html:

```html
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1">
```

где 1 = 1 секунда...

Можно через javascript с кнопкой

```js
<a href="Ссылка" onclick="location.reload(); alert('ok'); return false;">Обновить страницу</a>
```

Comment: у меня есть кнопка добавить товар в избранное на разных страницах, я хочу при добавлении товара в избранное просто перезагружать страницу и уведомлять что все ок

Comment: @Kirill дополнил вариант для кнопки

Comment: не совсем то, мне скорее нужно средствами джанго, мне нужно попасть на ту же страницу после добавления товара в бд.